# Mysql query in php and store result in $VAR

Tags: php, mysql

Here is a MySQL query:

```
SELECT Date(column_dt) from Table_nm;
```

I wanted to store Date value in `$VAR`.

```
$sql="select Date(Column_dt) from Table_nm";
if (!$DB->real_query($sql)){
                echo 'Error in query: check: Are your login ?';
    }
    $result = $DB->store_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);  
    $XX=$row['Date'];
    echo $XX;
```

Comment: Please show us your php code. Also right now your question is very unclear

Comment: Ok see I have attached code there.

Comment: It's worth checking to see if the connection was successful (you've not provided that code). What database library are you using - is this PDO or mysqli?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your SQL query. You are trying to access the value via a column name which doesn't exist. You have to alias the result of the function `Date()` in your SQL.

**Change**

```
$sql="select Date(Column_dt) from Table_nm";
```

**To**

```
$sql="select Date(Column_dt) AS `Date` from Table_nm";
```